# Python remove endline characters using Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I am trying to remove endline characters using regex. The example is as below

```
"\\r\\nMacBook 2018\\r\\nApple watch S3\\r\\n11   iPad pro\\\\r\\\\napple pencil"
```

I have tried using regex like below.

```
import re
text = "\\r\\nMacBook 2018\\r\\nApple watch S3\\r\\n11   iPad pro\\\\r\\\\napple pencil"
print(text)
text=re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',text)
print(text)
text=re.sub(r'(?:^| )\w(?:$| )', ' ', text).strip()
print(text)
text=re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
print(text)

\r\nMacBook 2018\r\nApple watch S3\r\n11   iPad pro\\r\\napple pencil
 r nMacBook 2018 r nApple watch S3 r n11   iPad pro  r  napple pencil
nMacBook 2018 nApple watch S3 n11   iPad pro   napple pencil
nMacBook 2018 nApple watch S3 n11 iPad pro napple pencil
```

I am still having some words like nmacbook, napple.
How do I clean it properly and have result like below

```
MacBook 2018 Apple watch S3 11 iPad pro apple pencil
```

Comment: For the desired result try: [`text = re.sub(r'(?:\\+[rn]|\s)+',' ',text).strip()`](https://tio.run/##Nc7BasJAFIXh/TzFQRdJiEpTNyKI6L4gdNnbxXRyJYPJzOXOFC303VONdPvxHzjyk7sY1uPoB4maoWxM5lvGDjMiJQpv1h1jvOD1pdk85SDSM642uw7v66c1DQB/si1EI9GEd7ZTKhyc72fGzDFMqxgYUTFEZXByVriF02V/fui185mTWMewoUVWP/xfUl6l769Si3K/Jao/NHz@UqrqYlGgWDyiapXuAykrY0R9yOWE4/gH)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern `\\\\r\\\\n` or `\\r\\n`

```
import re

text = "\\r\\nMacBook 2018\\r\\nApple watch S3\\r\\n11   iPad pro\\\\r\\\\napple pencil"


clean_text = re.sub(r"(\\\\r\\\\n|\\r\\n)", " ", text)

print(clean_text)
```

Output :

> MacBook 2018 Apple watch S3 11   iPad pro apple pencil

[image: output screenshot]

OR

try to divide into 2 steps if it works, accept the answer

```
text = "\\r\\nMacBook 2018\\r\\nApple watch S3\\r\\n11   iPad pro\\\\r\\\\napple pencil"

# Step 1: Remove the escape characters \r and \n
step1_text = text.replace(r'\r', '').replace(r'\n', '')

# Step 2: Remove backslashes and extra spaces, and create a sentence
words = step1_text.split('\\')
step2_text = ' '.join(words).strip().replace('  ', ' ')

print(step2_text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This works however what if we have text with \\\\\\r\\\\\\.

Comment: As backslash in regex and python collides with their usages, it should be either mentioned in the raw form based using or condition or use double-slash to match a single slash as per this [regex to escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re). Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can always combine operations and replace with a space.
One option.

```
import re

text = "\\r\\nMacBook 2018\\r\\nApple watch S3\\r\\n11   iPad pro\\\\r\\\\napple pencil"

text = re.sub(r'(?:[ \t]*\\+[rn])+[ \t]*|\s*([ \t])\s*', ' ', text).strip()

print(text)
```

Output

```
MacBook 2018 Apple watch S3 11 iPad pro apple pencil
```

Or, with just a whitespace `\s` construct.

```
import re

text = "\\r\\nMacBook 2018\\r\\nApple watch S3\\r\\n11   iPad pro\\\\r\\\\napple pencil"

text = re.sub(r'(?:\s*\\+[rn])+\s*|\s+', ' ', text).strip()


print(text)
```